# onscroll при отсутствии сколла

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Есть такой код, который говорит, что при скроллинге скролл достигнул конца страницы.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
      console.log('hey!');
});
```

Нормально работает.
Но на десктопной версии событие не обрабатывается, если страница не имеет скролла (свойство overflow не учитывается в условии, очевидно, но и не надо).
А нужно отрабатывать всегда, есть он или нет, при скроллинге страницы.
Как сделать код универсальнее под эту ситуацию? Также прошу подумать о мобильном скроллинге. Отлавливать конкретно колёсико было бы не лучшим решением, я думаю.

Comment: Что означает `при скроллинге страницы` при отсутствии скролла? Вращение колёсика?

Comment: А ничего другого нет, кроме колеса и touch, если scroll недоступен. Так что нравится колесо или нет, придется с ним дружить.

Comment: @vp_arth, да, скроллинг страницы вращением колесика происходит на компе. Вернее само событие `onscroll` его не обрабатывает, если видимого скролла  нет на страницы. И ведь в телефоне ведь нет никакого колёсика, так что под скроллингом понимается процесс, а не кручение колёсика как таковое.

Comment: Ну вот я, собственно и спрашиваю, что именно вы хотите обрабатывать в телефоне, если на странице нет скролла? Попытку потянуть страницу? События `wheel`/`touchmove` не подходят? Почему?

Comment: @vp_arth, я не говорил, что не подходят. Но хотелось бы кроссбраузерное и мультиплатформенное решение. Я не знаю какое оно может быть...

Comment: Я чего-то не понял фразы, если «страница не имеет скролла», то как вообще происходит скроллинг страницы и откуда событию вообще взяться?

Comment: @andreymal, вот именно, в этом и проблема, что событие не обрабатывается, так как скролла нет.  Нужно сделать так, чтобы событие отрабатывало в обычном режиме, как будто скролл есть и можно его задействовать.

Comment: Всё ещё не понимаю, то есть нужно разрешить скролл при overflow:hidden?

Comment: @andreymal, событие `onscroll` не работает при отсутствии скролла. Нужно, чтобы навешанное событие `onscroll` отрабатывало, как будто этот скролл есть, хотя, повторюсь, скроллинга как такового не происходит (просто представь пустую страницу, там нет никакой полосы прокрутки и никакого скроллинга не получится).

Comment: Кажется, до меня дошло) Правда, решения я таки не знаю

Comment: @andreymal, в кроссбраузерности загвоздка-то. Потому что отдельно ставить и отлавливать события для колёсика и для тачскрина будет неразумно и нерационально, мне кажется. Через пень-колоду всё можно сделать, даже это, но я тут для поиска эргономичного решения задал вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разве что так:

```
window.addEventListener('newscroll', function (e) {
    // обработка
}, false);

window.onwheel = function(e) {
    var event = new Event('newscroll');
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}

document.ontouchmove = function(e) {
    var event = new Event('newscroll');
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Но это не во всех браузерах работает.

А вот такое должно сработать везде, в ie6 точно:

```
document['newscroll'] = function(e) {
    // обработка
}

document.onmousewheel = function(e) {
    document['newscroll']({type:'newscroll'});
}

document.touchmove = function(e) {
    document['newscroll']({type:'newscroll'});
}
```

Если нет скролла, то без ловли колеса вряд ли получится.

Comment: Видимо без таких костылей действительно не обойтись, спасибо.